# Can't catch WCF FaultException in my client app

Tags: c#, wcf

I have my WCF service in which I've defined an operation and implemented it. In this method, I throw a `FaultException`.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class AQI : IAQI
{
    public void ControlModule(string moduleId, bool turnOn)
    {
        throw new FaultException("test error.");
    }
}
```

In my `IService` file, I have this code:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IAQI
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ControlModule(string moduleId, bool turnOn);
}
```

Then, I have my client app, which is a console app. In this app, I've created a class with the following code:

```
public class AQIClass
{
     private AQIClient client;

     public AQIClass()
     {
         client = new AQIClient( new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:64827/Service1.svc?singleWsdl") );
         client.Open();

         Console.WriteLine("Povezava je bila uspešno vzpostavljena.");
     }
   
     public async Task KrmiliModule(string sensorId, bool stanje)
     {
        try
        {
            await client.ControlModuleAsync(sensorId, stanje);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException");
            client.Abort();
        }
        catch (FaultException<ErrorInSettings> fesh)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fesh.Detail.message);
            client.Abort();
        }
        catch (FaultException fe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FaultException");
            client.Abort();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CommunicationException");
            Console.WriteLine(ce.Message);
            client.Abort();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Stanje modula je bilo uspešno spremenjeno.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        client.Close();
    }

    public void AbortConnection()
    {
        client.Abort();
    }
}
```

I use this class in my main program with the following code:

```
AQIClass aqi = new AQIClass();
aqi.KrmiliModule("1", false);
```

I use `wsHttpBinding` binding.

When I start WCF in debugging mode, I can see that an error is being thrown, but it is not being caught in my client code within the try-catch statement.

Comment: Have you tried catching `Exception`?

Comment: if the method that throw exception is void then it doesn't catch it, otherwise it does

Comment: That is because `IsOneWay = true`

Comment: You could hit a breakpoint or output to see where the runtime threw the exception.